# Dynamic Tabs with dynamic content using ComponentResolver in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Inspired by [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components) and [Passing Input while creating Angular 2 Component dynamically using ComponentResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487977/passing-input-while-creating-angular-2-component-dynamically-using-componentreso) I'm trying to go one step further and have not just the tabs get a dynamic component but also the content of be tab be comprised of dynamic components.
From the original example I used components C1-C3 for the tabs and want to use C4 and C5 for sections. I'm aware there isn't any styling/functionality for actually tabbing but the structure should be enough to get me on my way.
[I made this.](https://plnkr.co/edit/k9LKK9etbmCveNZxibJy?p=preview)

```
//our root app component
import {Component, ComponentRef, Input, ViewContainerRef, ComponentResolver, ViewChild, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dcl-wrapper',
  template: `<div #target></div>`
})
export class DclWrapper {
  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
  @Input() type;
  cmpRef:ComponentRef;
  private isViewInitialized:boolean = false;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver) {}

  updateComponent() {
    if(!this.isViewInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.type.type).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
      this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
      this.cmpRef.instance.info = this.type;
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.updateComponent();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isViewInitialized = true;
    this.updateComponent();  
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }    
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-dcl-wrapper',
  template: `<div #target></div>`
})
export class ChildDclWrapper {
  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
  @Input() type;
  cmpRef:ComponentRef;
  private isViewInitialized:boolean = false;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver) {}

  updateComponent() {
    if(!this.isViewInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.type.type).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
      this.cmpRef = this.target.createComponent(factory);
      this.cmpRef.instance.info = this.type;
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.updateComponent();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isViewInitialized = true;
    this.updateComponent();  
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.cmpRef) {
      this.cmpRef.destroy();
    }    
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'c1',
  template: `<h2>c1</h2><p>{{info.name}}</p>
            <my-sections [sections]="section"></my-sections>`

})
export class C1 {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'c2',
  template: `<h2>c2</h2><p>{{info.name}}</p>
            <my-sections [sections]="section"></my-sections>`
})
export class C2 {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'c3',
  template: `<h2>c3</h2><p>{{info.name}}</p>
            <my-sections [sections]="section"></my-sections>`

})
export class C3 {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'c4',
  template: `<h2>c4</h2><p>{{info.name}}</p>`

})
export class C4 {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'c5',
  template: `<h2>c5</h2><p>{{info.name}}</p>`

})
export class C5 {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-sections',
  directives: [ChildDclWrapper],
  template: `
  <h3>Sections</h3>
  <div *ngFor="let section of type.sections">
    <child-dcl-wrapper [type]="section"></child-dcl-wrapper>
  </div>
`
})
export class Sections {
  @Input() sections;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-tabs',
  directives: [DclWrapper],
  template: `
  <h2>Tabs</h2>
  <div *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    <dcl-wrapper [type]="tab"></dcl-wrapper>
  </div>
`
})
export class Tabs {
  @Input() tabs;
}

@Injectable()
export class AService {
  info = [
    {
      name: "taco",
      type: C1,
      sections: [
        {
          name: "believe",
          type: C4
        },
        {
          name: "car",
          type: C5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "pete",
      type: C2,
      sections: [
        {
          name: "repeat",
          type: C4
        },
        {
          name: "banana",
          type: C5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "carl",
      type: C3,
      sections: [
        {
          name: "shotgun",
          type: C4
        },
        {
          name: "helmet",
          type: C5
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  getServiceInfo() {
    console.log("Bung.");
    return this.info;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [Tabs],
  providers: [AService],
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <my-tabs [tabs]="types"></my-tabs>
`
})
export class App extends OnInit {
  types;
  aService;

  constructor(private aService: AService) {
    this.aService = aService;
  }

  getInfo() {
    console.log("beep");
    this.types = this.aService.getServiceInfo();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("boop");
    this.getInfo();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well crud, just call me Mr. Overcomplicater.

Comment: @yurzui, throw an answer down below and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several errors in your code. For example you need to use `info.sections` instead just `section` in the following code:

```
<my-sections [sections]="section"></my-sections>
```

It should be:

```
<my-sections [sections]="info.sections"></my-sections>
```

Also you forgot to add `Sections` directive like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'c1',
  template: `<h2>c1</h2><p>{{info.name}}</p>
            <my-sections [sections]="info.sections"></my-sections>`,
  directives: [Sections] <== add this line

})
export class C1 {}
```

And you can use one `DclWrapper` to do that.

The updated plunkr is here https://plnkr.co/edit/JRyqou9yC6LvSRrCR3eA?p=preview