# Not able to load component dynamically

Tags: angular

I tried to create a sample application where I wanted to load a component dynamically on a button click event from the parent component. But when I click on the button the component is not loaded instead I am getting the following error in the browser console. Please visit the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gPVvyKAuwIIm0aKRZ3l6?p=preview) for application code

```
zone.js:461Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined
    at eval (https://run.plnkr.co/EQ3xbfuUPWfMTU2C/src/app.ts!transpiled:38:45)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12/dist/zone.js:323:29)
    at Object.onInvoke (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9100:45)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12/dist/zone.js:322:35)
    at Zone.run (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12/dist/zone.js:216:44)
    at https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12/dist/zone.js:571:58
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12/dist/zone.js:356:38)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9091:45)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12/dist/zone.js:355:43)
    at Zone.runTask (https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12/dist/zone.js:256:48)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query for `@ViewChild(Loader, ...)` you need to ensure it was instantiated. For this you need to add `Loader` to `directives: [...]`

```
  directives: [Loader]
})
export class App {
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/nXspoJk1KZJMtP1Vn59f?p=preview)

Comment: I accept this answer, the same logic/code i have applied in my project and tried it locally, i included the component to be loaded in the directives. but still I am getting the exception in the browser console and the component not loaded properly. can you please respond to this query  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360904/typeerror-cannot-read-property-createcomponent-of-undefined

Comment: In the plunker shared by you, it is creating the instances multiple times one below the other, instead is it possible to replace the existing instance with the new instance when I click on the button i.e. at any point of time I wanted only one instance to be loaded, any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about your comment. The "inbox" is not as comfortable as it could be when you get a lot of comments ... I answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442546/how-to-avoid-creating-multiple-instance-of-the-same-component