# How to avoid creating multiple instance of the same component

Tags: typescript, angular

Please refer the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nXspoJk1KZJMtP1Vn59f?p=preview), in that you can notice the child component "Loader" is loaded multiple times whenever the button is clicked i.e. on every click a new instance is being created.

How do I avoid creating multiple instance of the same component? My requirement whenever the button is clicked the new instance should replace the existing? how to do this?

Parent component

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentResolver, Injector, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Loader} from './Loader';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <input type="button" (click)="onclick($event)" value="Click"/>
      <h3>Loading component</h3>
      <load></load>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Loader]
})
export class App {
  constructor(private _injector: Injector, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private _cr: ComponentResolver) {
    this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)';
    console.log("in constructor of App");
  }
   @ViewChild(Loader, { read: ViewContainerRef }) childContainer;

  onclick(event)
  {
     this._cr.resolveComponent(Loader).then(cmpFactory => {
          console.log("Creating component");

          this.childContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory,null, this._injector);
          let cmpRef = this.childContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory);
          cmpRef.instance.ParentID = "55";  

      });

  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `cmpRef` and call `cmpRef.destroy()` before you create a new instance

```
  onclick(event)
  {
     this._cr.resolveComponent(Loader).then(cmpFactory => {
          if(this.cmpRef) {
            this.cmpRef.destroy();
            this.cmpRef = null;
          }
          console.log("Creating component");

          //this.childContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory,null, this._injector);
          this.cmpRef = this.childContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory);
          this.cmpRef.instance.ParentID = "55";  

      });

  }
```

Comment: Can you please correct it in the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/8H7oz8Yeia9F3NQ3sgyi?p=preview   The suggested changes is not working in it?

Comment: There are two variants of `createComponent` in the Plunker, one with passing the injector and one without. `destroy()` is only called for the one where `cmpRef` is stored. Therefore for each click two components were created but only one destroyed. I commented out one `createComponent` https://plnkr.co/edit/VyFdZOT8CoElkSQ129jc?p=preview

Comment: understood the mistake, but even now if you notice there are 2 instances of the Loader component is rendered i.e. first instance during the time of page load and the second during the click event. How to avoid during the page load i.e. my need is to load only during the click event?

Comment: One is added statically by `<load></load>` in the `AppComponent` template. Just delete this line ;-)

Comment: I tried deleting that line already before posting, in that case it doesn't load any instance. even tried adding a div tag with id as "load".  <div id="load"></div>. In both cases it doesn't even load any single instance. ?