# Load dynamically component inside modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I need to load dynamically a custom component inside a modal and make it as flexible as possible.

For example :

-HTML CODE-

```
<button id="floating_button" class="floating_button animation_floating_in" (click)="createNewPost('new_post_form_modal')"><i class="material-icons">gesture</i></button>
      <div class="modal-content" id="loadHere" >
          <!-- LOAD MY CUSTOM COMPONENT HERE  -->
      </div>
```

-TYPE SCRIPT CODE-

```
public createNewPost(nomeComponent:any)
{
    // Load dynamically here nomeComponent inside div with id="loadHere"
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Comment: I tried a lot but dynamic component loader was changed and there are some error...I think it isn't possibile right now...I just create different modal component...

Answer (score 0):

you may create components dynamically like below,

```
   @Component({
     selector: "parent",
     template: `<button id="floating_button" class="floating_button animation_floating_in" (click)="createNewPost('new_post_form_modal')"><i class="material-icons">gesture</i></button>
  <div class="modal-content" #loadHere >
      <!-- LOAD MY CUSTOM COMPONENT HERE  -->
  </div>`
   })
   export class ParentComponent {
      @ViewChild("loadHere", { read: ViewContainerRef }) childContainer: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private _cr: ComponentResolver) {}

    createNewPost = (componentName): void => {
       componentToLoad = 'resolve component here using componentName'; 
       this._cr.resolveComponent(componentToLoad ).then(cmpFactory => {               
          this.childContainer.createComponent(cmpFactory);
       });
     }
   }
```

If you want to pass some parameters you may see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487977/passing-input-while-creating-angular-2-component-dynamically-using-componentreso)