# Angular 4 Dynamic component loading & emitting data to parent component

Tags: angular, output, components, angular4-forms, dynamic-ui

I am on process of creating poc for dynamic form generation using custom components.

i have succeeded upto some extent, where i can create form using set of dynamic components according to a json array. Now i am stuck in one instance where i just need to get output or rather the data out of these components ones the user have update the relevant inputs.

I had a look at the @output decorator and the eventEmitter yet i couldn't get a proper solution out of it. Much appreciate if any one in the community could give me some headsup :)

please follow the [PLUNKER](https://embed.plnkr.co/nVekM3/) to view the current progress and my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, There are two approaches you can use here

(i) Service

(ii) Using eventEmitter - output decorator

Since the components are dynamic you can always subscribe and the service can send the data back to app.ts.

Inorder to get an idea have a look at this **[`Passing Input while creating Angular 2 Component dynamically using ComponentResolver`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487977/passing-input-while-creating-angular-2-component-dynamically-using-componentreso)**

In your example, I modified service **`addDynamic`** component method and added Output events to each component, that will  belongs to app.ts

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/hzHKYhj0mx1Kkn2fWsAR?p=preview)**